# Service Layer & Web API Service Layer?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I have an application that has layers for data access, business, and wcf service. I need to convert this WCF layer to Web API and am stuck on whether I should:

1) Create two service layers/projects:
- Services (class library)
- Services.Api (WebAPI to expose and wrap calls to the services class library)

2) Or, just create a single WebAPI project.

I guess the issue I see with #2 is it limits how I'm able to reuse the library - I can only use the services using REST. With #1, I have the ability to use the class library when needed inside of my web controllers and WebAPI on the client/ajax as needed. The issue I see with #1 is all the extra code needed to repeat calls to the service layer class library.

Hope that make sense. Please let me know your thoughts on what might be a good approach and practice for me to follow, or scream at me for my lack of understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have a good business layer that itself should be your Services(class library) layer. On top your Business/Services layer, should be your front end layers which could be the Wcf, Api or Mvc.

```
ProjectName
 -ProjectName.Core (All poco classes and interfaces)
 -ProjectName.Data (All entity framework stuff)
 -ProjectName.Service (All business logic)
 -ProjectName.Web (All font end logic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 leaves you with more reusable code, which I think is almost always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should not be considered just from the point of view of yet another API variation.

I would go with 1).

The separation of services from the communication piece will provide many benefits when the system complexity increases, when API versioning may become an issue, during unit testing it, etc.

A few additional thoughts: call the layer not `Services.Api`, but something more specific to the type of endpoints that it exposes and enforce the separation of concerns by restricting what references are available in the `Api` layer to avoid the possibility of mixing of concerns when developers cut corners as the system evolves (i.e. don't make access to repositories, domain or DTO models, etc. available in the Api projects).

And if you do the above, I think the repetition of code can be extremely minimal.